# Could some explain this C output?

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Could anyone explain these undefined behaviors (i = i++ + ++i , i = i++, etc…)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949433/could-anyone-explain-these-undefined-behaviors-i-i-i-i-i-etc)

```
#include<stdio.h>
void call(int,int,int);

int main(){

int a=10;
call(a,a++,++a);
return 0;   
}

void call(int x,int y,int z){
printf("x=%d y=%d z=%d\n",x,y,z);
}
```

This code is giving me output of 12 11 12 when run it. Could someone explain exactly how this is happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The behaviour of your code is [undefined](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) since you're changing `a` twice between [sequence points](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_point):

```
call(a,a++,++a);
```

Answer (score 3):

The `behaviour is undefined` because changing a variable twice between two sequence points.

```
c99 standard : 5.1.2.3 Program execution
```

2

```
"Accessing a volatile object, modifying an object, modifying a file, or calling a function
that does any of those operations are all `side effects` which are changes in the state of
the `execution environment`. Evaluation of an expression may produce side effects. At
certain specified points in the execution sequence called `sequence points`, all side effects
of previous evaluations shall be complete and no side effects of subsequent evaluations
shall have taken place."
```

Here you are modifying a variable `a` twice between two sequence points.

Extended EDIT : If you know these concept already and thinking about that `,` comma operator is a sequence point so it should work as a `well defined`program.Then you are wrong `,` used here in function call is `comma separator` not `comma operator`